# Undefined reference C++ and openMPI

Tags: c++, openmpi

this is a practice for university. I'm getting all the time "undefined reference" when I'm trying to compile and I don't understand where my mistake is. We are working with openMPI and amazon EC2 machines for distributed computation. I really don't have any experience with distributed computation or any use of this programming paradigm, my professor doesn't answer my emails and my deadline is in three days.

I have searched online and didn't find anything that would help me.
This is the output I'm getting when trying to compile:

```
[ 77%] Linking CXX executable http_server
CMakeFiles/http_server.dir/httpserver.cpp.o: In function `httpServer::resolveRequests(int)':
/home/ubuntu/http_server/httpserver.cpp:410: undefined reference to `filemanager_stub::filemanager_stub(char*, char*)'
/home/ubuntu/http_server/httpserver.cpp:464: undefined reference to `filemanager_stub::filemanager_stub(char*, char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/http_server.dir/build.make:226: recipe for target 'http_server' failed
make[2]: *** [http_server] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:141: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/http_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/http_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
ubuntu@:~/http_server/build$
```

I have one httpserver.cpp running on one machine, which display a simple html where I can select which process I want to run (this process will run on another machine). I'm having problems with one concrete process, 'filemanager'.

I manage the POST request and then we got into here, this is in httpserver.cpp:

```
if(filemanager != NULL)
{

    FILE *fp;
    std::string copyFiles = "scp -i ~/cluster_pem2.pem.txt  ~/http_server/build/rpc_filemanager ubuntu@" + 
                    std::string(ip_machine)+":/home/ubuntu/";

    fp = popen(copyFiles.c_str(), "r");
    pclose(fp);

    this->file_manager = new filemanager_stub(ip_machine, "/home/ubuntu");

}
```

Four first lines are for copy the process to the machine where I want to run the process, this lines works fine and don't have any problem.
Next line is where the problem is. I'm getting the above output.
`this->file_manager` is declared in http_server.h like this: `filemanager_stub* file_manager = nullptr;`
`ip_machine` is where I capture the machine the process will run on. is declared a few lines above like this:`char ip_machine[64];`
Now the header of filemanager_stub:

```
#ifndef FILEMANAGER_STUB_H
#define FILEMANAGER_STUB_H
#include "mpi_manager.h"


class filemanager_stub
{
    MPI_Comm* comm;
public:
    filemanager_stub(char* ip,char* dir);
    std::vector<std::string*>* listFiles();
    void readFile(char* fileName, char** data, unsigned int* dataLength);
    void writeFile(char* fileName, char* data, unsigned int dataLength);
    ~filemanager_stub();
};

#endif // FILEMANAGER_STUB_H
```

I don't know if CMakeFile is interesting for this error but here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(http_server LANGUAGES CXX)

set (PROJECT_HTTPSERVER http_server)
set (PROJECT_PRUEBACLASE rpc_pruebaclase)
set (PROJECT_REMOTEFILE rpc_remotefile)
set (PROJECT_FILEMANAGER rpc_filemanager)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

project(${PROJECT_HTTPSERVER})
add_executable(${PROJECT_HTTPSERVER} "pruebaclase_stub.h" "pruebaclase_stub.cpp" "mpi_manager.h" "mpi_manager.cpp" "remotefile_stub.cpp"
                "remotefile_stub.h" "main.cpp" "httpserver.cpp" "httpserver.h" "utils.cpp" "utils.h")

project(${PROJECT_PRUEBACLASE})
add_executable(${PROJECT_PRUEBACLASE} "main_slave.cpp" "pruebaclase_imp.h" "pruebaclase_imp.cpp" "pruebaclase.h" "pruebaclase.cpp"
                "mpi_manager.h" "mpi_manager.cpp")

project(${PROJECT_REMOTEFILE})
add_executable(${PROJECT_REMOTEFILE} "main_remotefile.cpp" "mpi_manager.h" "mpi_manager.cpp" "remotefile.h" "remotefile.cpp"
                "remotefile_imp.cpp" "remotefile_imp.h")

project(${PROJECT_FILEMANAGER})
add_executable(${PROJECT_FILEMANAGER} "main_fm.cpp" "filemanager.h" "filemanager.cpp"
               "filemanager_imp.h" "filemanager_imp.cpp" "mpi_manager.h" "mpi_manager.cpp")

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_HTTPSERVER} ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_PRUEBACLASE} ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_REMOTEFILE} ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_FILEMANAGER} ${MPI_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(http_server pthread m rt atomic dl)
```

You can see 3 processes apart from httpserver, prueblaclase and remotefile do work both, the problem is with the last one.

I'm compiling in an amazon ec2 machine with cmake and make commands.
I think the code is understandable, I tried to write as little as possible, please at this point I don't try to make efficient code I just want it to run.

Thank you.

Comment: Your target `${PROJECT_HTTPSERVER}` needs definitions from `filemanager_stub.cpp` (probably), but this file is not compiled with that target.

Comment: you didnt include the definition of the constructor. If it is missing you would get that linker error

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that was the problem, I needed to add both _stub files to the definition of `${PROJECT_HTTPSERVER}`  Thank you you both @idclev463035818 for the quick answer you saved my life!!